# UK visa for pregnant partner

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, eu-citizens

I'm a EU citizen residing in the UK. I have an european passport so I'm allowed to live and work here. My girlfriend of four months is Brazilian and her visa is expiring in two months and we've recently found out that she is pregnant. We didn't plan this but since she's a catholic we're having the baby. Obviously, we both got our lives here and since she is having my child, the last thing I want is her having to return back to her country to give birth. She was married before but because she divorced, her visa will not be valid anymore.

Is there anything we can do to extend her visa to make sure she stays with me until our baby is born?

Answer (score 2):

She will have to inform the government and apply for her own visa.  I strongly recommend having her talk with an immigration lawyer or Citizen aAdvice Bureau.

https://www.gov.uk/visas-when-you-separate-or-divorce

https://www.gov.uk/remain-in-uk-family